# Check if a php script is executed in fpm environment

Tags: php, fpm

I want to detect if my script is being executed in fpm or in a different environment (like the php integrated webserver or apache modphp). My search didn't turn up any results. Apart from configuration instructions there seems to be close to no documentation on fpm.

Comment: `isset($_SERVER['FCGI_SERVER_VERSION'])`